# Paypal Payments - What to store from them?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I was wondering, if you have coded a website which uses paypal payments as a payment method (the kind of payments where you get redirected to their site for payment, not web payment pro).

What kind of details can I store? Is it just their paypal email address that can get supplied to me or do other details regarding their paypal account also get sent to me via their API which can be stored on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, you get the details of the transaction, so email address, name, delivery address and the contents of the shopping cart.

You can send custom parameters from your form though, such as phone number.

Paypal, by default doesn't ask users to provide a phone number and therefore usually doesn't send you one. However, it's often useful for retailers to have a customers phone number.

If your shopping cart is populated by your website and then customers are asked to complete a brief, name, phone number, email form before submitting to Paypals site you can send these extra form fields to Paypal and have them come back to your server for storage/checking.

However... I found it very erratic! There seemed to be a problem with my account when I did this and the PP technical team couldn't explain why it was only sometimes working! I gave up in the end and found a Payment gateway with credit card and Paypal integration, now all my payments come through the same channel and callback methods regardless of type.

http://www.securehosting.com I use now.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly only the details pertaining to the transaction can be retrieved in the usual procedure, as it appears even when you see the transaction details in your paypal account when you receive payments. However, it would be helpful for you if you can provide more information on what you wish to look for.